# Oracle Automated Stats Collection not Analyzing Some tables

Tags: oracle, database-performance, administration

I have turned on automated stats collection in my database.

select client_name, status from dba_autotask_client where client_name = 'auto optimizer stats collection'

auto optimizer stats collection ENABLED

But when I query the USER_TABLES, I see only some of the tables are being ANALYZED.

Comment: Is the stats job truly running?  Check this query, it should return results from today or maybe yesterday: `select start_time from dba_optstat_operations where operation = 'gather_database_stats (auto)' order by start_time desc;`

Comment: The auto stats job will only collect stats that the optimizer believes has a certain percentage of "stale" data. Also, the auto stats job runs within a maintenance window. If the number of tables that require stats exceeds that window, then some tables will be deferred to a subsequent window.